# How to check if all TextBoxes in a PowerPoint document are filled in

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint document where users can input text into several TextBoxes, over 6 slides in total.
On the last slide, **I want to check if the user has filled in every TextBox in the presentation**.

I tried using lots of code snippets on the internet and modifying them, however I am a complete VBA noob and, surprisingly, it did not work out. :')
I would greatly appreciate your help with this task.

*It would be even better if it is possible to check whether the user has input AT LEAST 4 characters in each textbox. However I have no idea how to start programming this...*

Here is my code, it does not show errors however nothing happens when clicking the CheckBox at the end.

```
Public Sub CheckTextBox()
    Dim fTextBox As Object
    For Each Slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each fTextBox In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If TypeName(fTextBox) = "TextBox" Then
            If fTextBox.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox "Please make sure to fill out all fields!"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Next
End Sub


'When ticking this CheckBox, the MsgBox should show up

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
CheckTextBox
End Sub
```

Thank you guys so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your inner `For`-loop is wrong, you need to loop over all `Shapes` of the slide, instead, you start another loop over all slides.

Basically, all objects that you place on a slide are `Shapes`. If you use `TypeName`, you will get `Shape`. To distinguish the single shape-types, use the property `type` of the shape-object. A list of types can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype - a textbox has a type `msoTextBox` (17).

To get the text of a shape, use the property `TextFrame.TextRange.Text` of the shape.

Try the following code (it checks already for a length of at least 4 characters). It will stop at the first textbox that has less than 4 chars in it (else, you would get one MsgBox for every textbox) and select it.

```
Public Sub CheckTextBox()
    Dim sh As Shape, slide As slide
    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each sh In slide.Shapes
            Debug.Print TypeName(sh)
            If sh.Type = msoTextBox Then
                If Len(sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) < 4 Then
                    MsgBox "Please make sure to fill out all fields!"
                    slide.Select
                    sh.Select
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
The code above didn't take into account the shapes within groups. The following code loops over all shapes of all slides and calls the function `checkShape` that will check
**a)** If the shape is a *textBox* (`msoTextBox`, 17) - if yes, the length of the text is checked and if too short, that shape is returned.
**b)** If the shape is a *group* (`msoGroup`, 6), it calls (recursively) the function for all child shapes and returns the first child textbox found.
The main routine (`CheckAllTextBoxes`) checks if any textBox was found, and, if yes, will select it and issue the message.

```
Public Sub CheckAllTextBoxes()
    Dim slide As slide, sh As Shape
    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each sh In slide.Shapes

            Dim textBox As Shape
            Set textBox = CheckShape(sh, 4)
            If Not textBox Is Nothing Then
                slide.Select
                textBox.Select
                MsgBox "Please make sure to fill out all fields!"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Function CheckShape(sh As Shape, minLen As Integer) As Shape

    ' Check if shape is a Textbox and then text is not long enough
    If sh.Type = msoTextBox Then
        If Len(sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) < minLen Then
            Set CheckShape = sh
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    ' For a group, check all it's child shapes
    If sh.Type = msoGroup Then
        Dim child As Shape
        For Each child In sh.GroupItems
            Dim textBox As Shape
            Set textBox = CheckShape(child, minLen)
            If Not textBox Is Nothing Then
                ' Found a Textbox within the group, return it
                Set CheckShape = textBox
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next child
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! The code looks good and I think I understand most of it. However, when using it in my presentation, nothing happens when I tick the checkbox.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and step thru it. It could also be possible that the event routine is not triggered.

Comment: I tried using a breakpoint and single steps to go through the code, but there are no errors. I am not sure what else to do. How can I prevent the event routine from not triggering?

Comment: The event routine is triggered if the name is correct - is the name of your checkbox really `CheckBox1`? While editing the slides, doubleclick on the checkbox - it should show your event routine. If not (it shows an empty routine), name (or place) of the routine was wrong.

When debugging: Is the code looping thru all your slides and shapes on this slide?

Comment: The name is correct, yes. When I enter some simple other code (like hide some element) instead of the one above, it triggers as intended.

I did a debugging with single steps again and noticed that the debugging works normally until this line:

`Debug.Print TypeName(sh)`

It then skips all of the following lines and goes straight to the second End If.
I suppose that is not intended, right?
The code also does not loop through any slides, but I am not sure if I am doing debugging right.

Comment: Have to admit that the Debug.Print statement was left there by accident  - anyhow: Change the line to `Debug.Print sh.Name, TypeName(sh), sh.Type` - if you don't see any `17`, you have something different, not a Textbox

Comment: Okay thank you for helping me fix that!
I changed the line. When hovering over `MsoTextBox` while debugging, it does say 17.
Now the single step debugger goes to line `If sh.Type = msoTextBox Then` and then  skips the rest and jumps to `End If` again.

Comment: `MsoTextBox` is just a name for the number 17 - but what is the output of the Debug.Print (what is the value of `sh.Type`)? You are familiar with the immediate window (Press [Ctrl]+[G])?

Comment: I am very sorry, I did not know about the output window.
So, the Debug-Print said `Picture Placeholder 5       Shape          14` the first time , then `Group 28      Shape          6` the second time.
The Value of sh.Type is 6.

Comment: Okay, now it's clear - the textboxes are within a `Group`. So you have to loop through all shapes of all groups also. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help so far.
Unfortunately nothing is happening with the new code either when the checkbox is clicked.
Could private or public subs be a problem? When I go on a slide with textboxes, the slide code looks like this: `Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_Change()

End Sub`

Comment: No, `privat` is okay. Have you notices that I changed the name of the routine? Are you using `Option explicit`?

Comment: Yes, I did add the new name in my checkbox.
I added Option explicit at the top of the code. Now it seems like the debugger just loops through the `Private Sub CheckAllTextBoxes()` indefinitely. It never goes to the CheckShape function. I wonder, is it possible to attach a plain .pptm file with just the textboxes, checkbox and code?

Comment: Sorry, had a typo - change the `0` to a `4` when calling `CheckShape` - updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I pasted in your new answer.
Unfortunately, the debugger is still looping through `CheckAllTextBoxes` without reading the rest of the code. Do you want to have a look at the presentation, by chance?
I do not want to waste your time and would definitely understand if you got better things to do with your time.

Comment: @si1rin My guess is that you've added ActiveX text boxes (ie, so that the user can enter text during a slide show), not regular PowerPoint text shapes, which would be static/uneditable during a slide show. FunThomas' (excellent) code wouldn't "see" text in active-x text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for c# code to list all text boxes in a presentation:

```cs
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using MsoShapeType = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType;

public static IEnumerable<Shape> AllTextBoxes (Presentation presentation) =>
    from slide in presentation.Slides.Cast<Slide>()
    from shape in slide.Shapes.Cast<Shape>()
    from textBox in AllTextBoxes(shape)
    select textBox;

public static IEnumerable<Shape> AllTextBoxes (Shape sh)
{
    IEnumerable<Shape> _() { if (sh.Type == MsoShapeType.msoTextBox) yield return sh; }
    return sh.Type == MsoShapeType.msoGroup ? sh.GroupItems.Cast<Shape>().SelectMany(AllTextBoxes) : _();
}
```